# Sometimes can't reboot on arm-device

Tags: arm, armbian

I have a little device on ARM with armbian on it.
It automatically loads after turning power on or after shutdown. But sometimes it doesn't until I turn off-on power.
I added a script to crontab. The script reboots device each few minutes and puts current time in text file.
Usually it reloads few times and then stops. LEDs are turned on but nothing on a monitor, the device isn't available through ssh and the script isn't working any more (no new timings of reboots in the text file).
I turned on saving logs for previous boots, so I can watch journalctl for previous boots. But it contains a lot of information and normal shutdowns have the same log-ending as these, which ended with power off.
What can I look for debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is usually caused by a faulty SD card or power supply.